# Query regarding eliminating an unknown function?

Tags: calculus

For an unknown function denoted by $g(x)$ its given that:

$\int^\infty_1 g(x) = C_0$

For another known function $h(x)$ its we know:

$\int^\infty_1 g(x)*h(x) = C_1$

here $C_0$ and $C_1$ are two known constants.

Now, using the above two, can we get create a 'reduced' integral equation that is dependent on only the function $h(x)$ (i.e. can we eliminate $g(x)$)?

Comment: No way. ${{{{{}}}}}$

Answer (score 1):

Take $h = 0$. $\int gh = 0$ for any $g$, but for any $C_0$ there exist **many** functions with $\int g = C_0$.

Comment: I see. But what I was thinking was can we repeatedly expand the second function into a series by using integration by parts repeatedly as: $\int^\infty_1 g(x)*h(x) =  h(x)*\int g(x) - \int (h(x)'* \int g(x))$

Comment: Now since the second series is convergent the last term tends to 0. Now, for all the term in this series we can substitute the $\int g(x)$ with the first equation's R.H.S. ?

Comment: any comments on this approach?

Comment: @TheoryQuest1, your idea **can't** work. For any (compatible) $h,C_0,C_1$ there are *many* $g$ verifying the conditions.

Comment: @TheoryQuest1, more: **why** "the second series [*what* series?]  is convergent"?